# Pandas how to assign all values to a column based on a cluster and another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of ids from a previous dataframe say [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and I have another dataframe say

dataframe with ids and clusters:

[image: img]

If there are matching ids in the dataframes I want to change all the ids group by the cluster to have that id. So the resulting dataframe will be

dataframe with ids matching first dataframe in clusters

[image: img2]

Comment: this would be fairly trivial to implement but one has to ask, what is the purpose of the id column? can you just get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
list_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [3, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'cluster': [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]})

true_values = df['cluster'] == list_ids
for num, value in enumerate(true_values):
    if not value:
        cluster_number = df['cluster'][num]
        cluster_id = df['cluster'].where(df['cluster'] == cluster_number)
        cluster_id = cluster_id.dropna().index[0]
        df['id'][num] = df['id'][cluster_id]


print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id  cluster
0   3        1
1   5        2
2   6        3
3   5        2
4   3        1
```